# Flash Actionscript 3 Simple Counter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, counter

I am struggling to make a simple flash actionscript 3 counter in a text field, that starts at the beginning of my animation at 0, and increases with each frame.

This will count up until it reaches a particular frame on the timeline, where I would like the number to begin doubling instead of counting up.

I can only seem to find AS2 examples, and i'm not too sure how to get the double part working. Can anyone out there help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using Flash CS and you are putting your code directly on the frames, so this snippet on the first frame should work.

Let's say you have a `TextField` on your stage with an instance name of `counterTextField`, and you want the count to start doubling up at frame 100.

```
import flash.events.Event;

var count:int = 0;
var limit:int = 100;
var increase:int = 1;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, countFrames);

function countFrames(e:Event):void
{
    if (count <= limit)
    {
         count += increase;
    }
    else
    {
         count *= 2;
    }
    counterTextField.text = String(count);
}
```

Comment: also in as3 you can no longer put code directly on your objects, instead you can put your code in .as files, or if you want to use the timeline, right click on a frame and use the actions panel.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added a dynamic text box with the instance name counterTextField and placed the action script on the timeline. I get this error for some reason 
Scene 1, Layer 'SCORE', Frame 1, Line 18 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type String.

Comment: yeah i edited the last line, forgot to convert int to string:) `counterTextField.text = String(count);`

Comment: hmmm I no longer get any errors but the timer just flashes 3 and 33 in a loop

Comment: that's weird, can you put a trace in there to see what the new text is?